# How do I find a percentage with only the mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, education, standard-deviation

'If we have a set of scores that are normally distributed and have a mean of 20 and a standard deviation of 5, what percentage of scores are greater than 20?'

Now I know the answer is 50%, because it was a multiple choice question and I guessed, but I've been trying to work it out.

How do I get to that 50% by only using the mean and the standard deviation?

How do I work it out without knowing the number of scores?

Comment: Normal distributions are symmetric about the mean..you don't even need the standard deviation.

Comment: So the mean 20 and the amount in the set of scores is 40? I'm not getting it.

Comment: Not seeing the $40$...as you point out, the problem does not give you enough information to determine the number of scores. But for any symmetric distribution the probability of being above (or equal to) the mean is the same as the probability of being below (or equal to) the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to find the percentage $p$ of values above a certain point $a$ in a normally distributed set with the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is to integrate the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) from $a$ to $\infty$. Thus this gives

$$p=\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

To find the percentage of values below $a$, integrate from $-\infty$ to $a$ which gives

$$p=\int_{-\infty}^a \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Note that this integral cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions, so to get a numerical answer you would have to use a calculator or another method of approximation. On a TI-84 and TI-89 I believe this function is
$$\text{normalcdf}\,(l_1,l_2,\mu,\sigma)$$
where $l_1$ and $l_2$ are the lower and upper limits of integration, respectively. In your case $l_1=20$, $l_2=\infty$, $\mu=20$, and $\sigma=20$. Because some calculators cannot take $\infty$ as an input, use $l_2=10^{99}$, so your calculator input should be 
$$\text{normalcdf}\,(20,10^{99},20,5)$$
which should return
$$p=0.5$$
as desired.

Also note that in a normal distribution half the values are above the mean and half the values are below the mean, so you don't even need to do any calculation to know that $p=0.5$ is the answer. The following picture of the [Empirical Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) can help you visualize the percentage of values within a certain number of standard deviations from the mean, aiding your intuitive understanding of the normal distribution.
[image: Empirical Rule]

Comment: Thanks so much, it's a little clearer.

Comment: I assume you've taken calculus and know that the integral of a function is the area underneath it's curve, right?